# Alternatives to Dataframe.iterrows() or Dataframe.itertuples()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

My understanding of a Pandas dataframe vectorization (through Pandas vectorization itself or through Numpy) is applying a function to an array, similar to .apply() (Please correct me if I'm wrong). Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'color' : ['red','blue','yellow','orange','green',
                         'white','black','brown','orange-red','teal',
                         'beige','mauve','cyan','goldenrod','auburn',
                         'azure','celadon','lavender','oak','chocolate'], 
               'group' : [1,1,1,1,1,
                          1,1,1,1,1,
                          1,2,2,2,2,
                          4,4,5,6,7]})
df = df.set_index('color')
df
```

[image]

For this data, I want to apply a special counter for each unique value in A. Here's my current implementation of it:

```
df['C'] = 0
for value in set(df['group'].values):
    filtered_df = df[df['group'] == value]
    adj_counter = 0
    initialize_counter = -1
    spacing_counter = 20
    special_counters = [0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,4,-4,5,-5,6,-6,7,-7]
    for color,rows in filtered_df.iterrows():
        if len(filtered_df.index) < 7:
            initialize_counter +=1
            df.loc[color,'C'] = (46+special_counters[initialize_counter])

        else:
            spacing_counter +=1
            if spacing_counter > 5:
                spacing_counter = 0
            df.loc[color,'C'] = spacing_counter
df
```

[image]

Is there a faster way to implement this that doesn't involve iterrows or itertuples? Since the counting in the C columns is very irregular, I'm not sure as how I could implement this through apply or even through vectorization

Comment: why did the counter go back to zero where `color == 'black'`?

Comment: Can you explain in words what is the counter supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is first create the column 'C' with `groupby` on the column 'group' and `cumcount` that would almost represent `spacing_counter` or `initialize_counter` depending on `if len(filtered_df.index) < 7` or not.

```
df['C'] = df.groupby('group').cumcount()
```

Now you need to select the appropriate rows to do the `if` or the `else` part of your code. One way is to create a series using `groupby` again and `transform` to know the `size` of the group related to each row. Then, use `loc` on you `df` using this series and do: if the value is smaller than 7, you can `map` your values with the `special_counters` else just use modulo `%` 6

```
ser_size = df.groupby('group')['C'].transform('size')
df.loc[ser_size < 7,'C'] = df.loc[ser_size < 7,'C'].map(lambda x: 46 + special_counters[x])
df.loc[ser_size >= 7,'C'] %= 6
```

at the end, you get as expected:

```
print (df)
            group   C
color                
red             1   0
blue            1   1
yellow          1   2
orange          1   3
green           1   4
white           1   5
black           1   0
brown           1   1
orange-red      1   2
teal            1   3
beige           1   4
mauve           2  46
cyan            2  47
goldenrod       2  45
auburn          2  48
azure           4  46
celadon         4  47
lavender        5  46
oak             6  46
chocolate       7  46
```